# How to use variables in angular translate pluralization?

Tags: angularjs, variables, angular-translate

I am trying to make the angular translate pluralization work with `$scope` variables. Everything works fine when the numbers are hard-coded in the HTML, but things get buggy when I am using my model's variables.

For instance, for this translation:

```
"PLURAL_TEXT": "{N, plural, =0{no results} one{1 result} other{# results} }"
```

This HTML piece:

```
{{"PLURAL_TEXT"|translate:"{N:2}"}}
```

Gives "2 results" which is OK.

But when I write this instead:

```
{{"PLURAL_TEXT"|translate:"{N:myarray.length}"}}
```

(where `$scope.myarray` is a JavaScript array) Then I get "1 result" even though `$scope.myarray.length` is 5, 0 or whatever.

So my question is how to use the pluralization with variables. All the examples I have found in the doc and elsewhere use hard-coded values. Many thanks!

(btw, I did not try to play with the switchable interpolation approach, with the 3rd parameter of the filter being 'messageformat', as I don't need this level of sophistication, and I believe it's pointless for my issue, but let me know if I am wrong).

Comment: `"{N:myarray.length}"` is just a string. `length` property won't interpolate. Maybe something like `{{"PLURAL_TEXT"|translate:("{N:" + myarray.length + "}")}}`.

Comment: Works great, many thanks!